# outline only on tab focus

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm looking for a simple, efficient solution for focus-able elements to have outline **only while pressing tab** and not show when using a mouse in **react** apps. (something like :focus-visible that actually works on different browsers)
-very frustrating that making an accessible website has almost no explained general explanation online.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to add an event listener to the keyboard and mouse press.
If it's tab keypress then add a CSS class that would outline the desired elements.

```
function handleFirstTab(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    document.body.classList.add('user-is-tabbing');

    window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab);
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDownOnce);
  }
}

function handleMouseDownOnce() {
  document.body.classList.remove('user-is-tabbing');

  window.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDownOnce);
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab);
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', handleFirstTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a general catch all for focus. If there are styles overriding focus you will have to include specificity or "!important" for these properties to work.

```
*:focus {
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: Highlight;
}

/* WebKit gets its native focus styles.
 */
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  *:focus {
    outline-color: -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-style: auto;
  }
}
```

reference: https://ghinda.net/article/mimic-native-focus-css/

Comment: Thank you! this will help me but my question was more focused on how to make this style show only when tabbing and not show when using a mouse